# what does the prefix T mean in type names for typescript

Tags: typescript, flowtype, flux

It seems like a common pattern to prefix types with the letter T.

Here's an example from [some flux code](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/2ab02c6e61618da270509dca7a8a40c852570f1b/examples/flux-async/flow/flux-utils.js#L32):

```js
  declare class ReduceStore<TPayload, TState> extends Store<TPayload> {
    getState(): TState;
    getInitialState(): TState;
    reduce(state: TState, action: TPayload): TState;
    areEqual(one: TState, two: TState): boolean;
  }
```

What is this pattern for? What is the difference between the State type and the TState type? Why doesn't TState need to be imported or defined anywhere, is that a typescript primitive?

Comment: It's a generic type variable. It doesn't refer to a specific type. Those are often prefixed with T in both TypeScript and C# to indicate that they refer to a type.

Comment: it's a generic type parameter. Its name is introduced in the declaration between the angle brackets and can be any valid identifier. The T prefix is just a convention used by some developers, and stands for type. Also, this is Flow and not TypeScript so TypeScript conventions are not really relevant

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is just a naming convention for [type arguments (aka generics)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Why? Type arguments are a unique kind of parameter in code (it doesn't represent a specific type or a value, rather it's a placeholder for some kind of type in that context) which is why it's useful to have some visually distinct naming pattern, for code readability.

In simple cases the name `T` is [often used](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b5210edf39148c9fbc68e872c703d358c5c22c5e/types/underscore/index.d.ts#L72) for a type argument:

```
interface Collection<T> {
  [index: number]: T;
}
```

If you have multiple type arguments it's also [common to use](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b5210edf39148c9fbc68e872c703d358c5c22c5e/types/react/index.d.ts#L393) different single letter capitals for each type argument:

```
class Component<P, S> {
  // In React `P` represents "Props" type, and `S` represents "State" type
}
```

However, that can get pretty hard to read! It's well understood that single letters like `T` and `S` are some kind of type argument, and not specific types, but imagine some code that references `P`, `S`, `R`, `SS`, and you have to sort out what that means while you read the code. It can get hard. So for better readability you could use a full name (there's no syntactical restrictions on type argument names):

```
class Component<Props, State> { }
```

That works fine. The problem is that `Props` and `State` look like they could be actual concrete types named `Props` and `State`, but they are not. So now you have a different kind of potential confusion. So finally, to preserve readability without losing the hint that they are placeholder type arguments and not specific types, use full names prefixed with `T` (for "Type argument"):

```
class Component<TProps, TState> { }
```

The only down-side to this is longer names, which is why you still see `T` and such commonly used, especially in contexts where an experienced programmer is going to naturally  know what that stands for, for  example `Collection<T>` is pretty clear, `Collection<TElement>` is not necessary, and to a React developer "props" and "state" is the bread-and-butter of using React, so `Component<P, S>` is going to be well known. It's still a style choice either way, in the end.

More info than you could have possibly wanted. :)

Comment: Thanks for the extended explainer!